# Only run task if another isn't UP-TO-DATE in gradle

Tags: gradle, task

I want to automatically add a serverRun task when doing functional tests in Gradle, so I add a dependency :

```
funcTestTask.dependsOn(serverRun)
```

Which results in the task running whether or not the funcTestTask even runs

```
:compile
:serverRun
:funcTestTask (and associate compile tasks... etc)
:serverStop

OR

:compile UP-TO-DATE
:serverRun <-- unnecessary 
:funcTestTask UP-TO-DATE
:serverStop
```

The cost of starting the server is pretty high and I only want it to start if the functionalTest **isn't** UP-TO-DATE, I'd like to do or something :

```
if(!funcTestTask.isUpToDate) {
    funcTestTask.dependsOn(serverRun)
}
```

So I know I can't know the up-to-date status of funcTestTask until all it's inputs/outputs are decided BUT can I inherit it's uptoDate checker?

```
serverRun.outputs.upToDateWhen(funcTestTask.upToDate)
```

The alternative is to "doFirst" the ServerRun in the FuncTest, which I believe is generally frowned upon?

```
funcTestTask.doFirst { serverRun.execute() }
```

Is there a way to conditionally run a task before another?

**UPDATE 1**
Tried settings inputs/outputs the same

```
serverRun.inputs.files(funcTestTask.inputs.files)
serverRun.outputs.files(funcTestTask.outputs.files)
```

and this seems to rerun the server on recompiles (good), skips reruns after successful unchanged functional tests (also good), but wont rerun tests after a failed test like the following

```
:compile
:serverRun
:funcTestTask FAILED

then

:compile UP-TO-DATE
:serverRun UP-TO-DATE <-- wrong!
:funcTestTask FAILED
```

Comment: You could effectively emulate this by simply making their inputs the same. I assume `funcTestTask` is some task of type `Test`? There must also be some task to compile those tests?

Comment: Yeah, it is of type Test.  But if a test fails where is that information cached?  Because the inputs remain the same but the task previously failed <-- can I get task failure information?

Comment: You can easily check if a task failed or not. The expression `task.state.failure == null` will be `true` for successful task executions.

Comment: But you can only know about success after the test has run.  What I want is to check if a task failed on a previous run (which affects the up-to-date status).

Comment: While running a failing test suite with the Gradle `-i` argument, it indicates the up-to-date check fails due to a change in the output directory. Perhaps add `test.binResultsDir` as an output directory?

Comment: That got me a little further, but I don't think I fully understand how gradle computes output directory changes. More info in UPDATE 1 as part of the question

Comment: Gradle may internally consider a task not up-to-date when its last execution failed. In this case, you could manually parse the test results output to determine if the last execution failed.

Comment: Yeah, maybe, however running with the INFO flag reveals the funcTestTask is running again after failure because it's outputs "have changed", so something about the outputs is different there.

Comment: My guess, and I'd have to debug through it to confirm, is that a failed task execution does not update task artifact state. Therefore, subsequent executions will always trigger based on the output having been changed. In other words, the test task creates an output, but Gradle does not take a snapshot of that output for use in future up-to-date checks since the task result was a failure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up writing to a 'failure file' and making that an input on the serverRun task:

```
File serverTrigger = project.file("${buildDir}/trigger") 

project.gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { TaskExecutionGraph taskGraph ->
  // make the serverRun task have the same inputs/outputs + extra trigger
  serverRun.inputs.files(funcTestTask.inputs.files, serverTrigger)
  serverRun.outputs.files(funcTestTask.outputs.files)
}

project.gradle.taskGraph.afterTask { Task task, TaskState state ->
  if (task.name == "funcTestTask" && state.failure) {
    serverRun.trigger << new Date()
  }
}
```

With information from an answer to my question on the Gradle forums :
http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/how-can-i-start-a-server-conditionally-before-a-functionaltestrun

Answer (score 7):

Having faced the same problem I found a very clean solution. In my case I want an eclipse project setup to be generated when the build is run, but only at the times when a new jar is generated. No project setup should be executed when the jar is up to date. Here is how one can accomplish that:

```
tasks.eclipse {
  onlyIf {
    !jar.state.upToDate
  }
}

build {
  dependsOn tasks.eclipse
}
```

Comment: This doesnt seem to work for me. state.upToDate always returns false, even when the task was actually later on considered up to date.

Comment: same for me, the state is not yet set when the onlyIf is executed

Answer (score 3):

Since the task is a dependent tasks of the one you are trying to control then you can try:

```
tasks {
    onlyIf {
        dependsOnTaskDidWork()
    }
}
```

Comment: This one worked for me: just `dependsOnTaskDidWork` is deprecated, but it can be replaced with `task.didWork`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but the solution I came up is much simpler.
This starts up the server only if testing is necessary

```
test {
    doFirst {
        exec {
            executable = 'docker/_ci/run.sh'
            args = ['--start']
        }
    }

    doLast {
        exec {
            executable = 'docker/_ci/run.sh'
            args = ['--stop']
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have `task1` and `task2` which depends on `task1` and you need to run `task2` only if task1 is not up-to-date, the following example may be used:

```
task task1 {
  // task1 definition
}

task task2(dependsOn: task1) {
  onlyIf { task1.didWork }
}
```

In this case task2 will run only when task1 is not up-to-date. It's important to use `didWork` only for tasks which are defined in `dependsOn`, in order to ensure that `didWork` is evaluated after that task (`task1` in our example) had chance to run.